# VBA Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture keeps pasting on initial document

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-word

The below code is part of a program that populates a word document from an access database.

This part of the code adds a picture with the user's signature at the bookmark location 'Signature'. For some reason it works the first attempt, but the nex time it runs it pastes at the initial document's bookmark location and not the new document.

```
appword.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Signature").Select

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
    SASignaturePath, _
    LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
```

I've attempted to use a few other selection commands like:

```
Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Signature"
```

and

```
objWork.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Signature").Range.Select
```

with no luck.

Edit: Adding additional info as requested.

The entire function pulls some global variables from access and autopopulates a word document with them. The global variable 'SASignaturePath' has the file location of the signature image.

Below is the entire function being called when the user presses the 'create cost letter' button.

```
    Function fillCostLetter()

Dim appword As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim Path As String
TodayDate = Format(Now(), "mmmm dd, yyyy")
On Error Resume Next
Error.Clear

Set appword = GetObject(, "word.application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set appword = New Word.Application
    appword.Visible = True
End If

Path = "Z:\DocFolder\ServiceAssociateToolBox\CostLetterTestStage.docx"

Set doc = appword.Documents.Open(Path, , True)


With doc
    .FormFields("Date").Result = TodayDate
    .FormFields("BillName").Result = BillName
    .FormFields("BillAmmount").Result = BillAmmount
    .FormFields("BillAddress").Result = BillAddress
    .FormFields("BillAmmount").Result = BillAmmount
    .FormFields("BillCity").Result = BillCity
    .FormFields("BillState").Result = BillState
    .FormFields("BillZip").Result = BillZip


    .FormFields("SiteZip").Result = SiteZip
    .FormFields("SiteState").Result = SiteState
    .FormFields("SiteCity").Result = SiteCity
    .FormFields("SiteStreetType").Result = SiteStreetType
    .FormFields("SiteStreetName").Result = SiteStreetName
    .FormFields("SiteStreetNo").Result = SiteStreetNo
    .FormFields("BillName2").Result = BillName
    .FormFields("WorkRequest").Result = WR_NO

    .FormFields("CustName").Result = CustName

    .FormFields("SAName").Result = SAName
    .FormFields("SADeptartment").Result = SADept
    .FormFields("SAPhone").Result = SAPhone

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Signature").Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
        SASignaturePath, _
        LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True


    Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=1

End With

appword.Visible = True
appword.Activate

Set doc = Nothing
Set appword = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to address handling different documents, so you'll need to explain exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Sure. This is in Access (office 2010). The application allows the user to select their name and type in a job #. It then creates a word document that autopopulates

Comment: How exactly does that happen?  There's clearly some problem with that part of your code if it's not updating the Word doc reference.

Comment: I updated the original post to include the entire function that's being called. The function calls the same file every time (its using it as the template letter). The user then would 'save as' the document. The rest of the code works and updates the text values, but the image updates on the first document created. If the first document created is closed, it just does not include the image. Thanks!

Comment: `doc` is a reference to the just-opened document, so try using that in place of `ActiveDocument`

Comment: THANKS TIM! That worked. changed the line to `doc.Bookmarks("Signature").Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
        SASignaturePath, _
        LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True`

Answer (score 0):

Changing and then using the selection as an insertion point is generally bad practice. What you should rather do is use the actual `Range` of the bookmark, which can be obtained by calling:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("BookmarkName").Range
```

The obtained `Range` can then be used in your above code instead of `Selection`, i.e.

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("BookmarkName").Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture (...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried using the `Range` of the bookmark as you suggested. The result was the same. It works correctly for the very first document created, but any time after that it inserts the image into the original document even though a new one is created correctly. I did not include the code that is used to create the file but it may be part of the problem. `Set appword = GetObject(, "word.application")` and `Set doc = appword.Documents.Open(Path, , True)`